# Sorting Python objects in a list by specific class attributes

Tags: python, sorting, object

I have been thinking about this for a while but I am not quite sure how best to approach this.
The problem I am trying to tackle is as follows:

a) Assume you start with a list of objects of the same type. 
b) Each of these objects has a name attribute of type string. 
c) The list should be sorted alphanumerically by the name attribute inside each object, with the exception that certain name elements must be on top of the sorted list.

I am thinking that I probably have to do a normal sort first, then filter for those prioritized elements out and pull them out of the list, and insert them to the top of the list. This will probably work, but sounds grossly inefficient. Can someone think of a way to do this in a more Pythonic way, either in Python 2.7 or 3?

Thanks!

Comment: You can sort with a key, and use the class attribute as a key.  Please provide a [mcve] of your other condition

Comment: Right, but remember I also need to have specific elements to be on the top as well as having a normal sort.

Comment: Please add some code in your question, if you have tried it.

Comment: Well, you haven't provided *any* actual code or information about your problem, so until you do, no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: I am on my phone now, will add this once I get back home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `key` attribute for the `sorted` function. The `key` can be any function and thus encapsulate your logic.

A common way to achieve priority in sorting is to rely on `tuple` ordering. You `key` will thus return a `(priority, attribute)` pair.

### Code

```
def priority_sort_key(attr, priority, default=float('inf')):
    def key_func(obj):
        key = getattr(obj, attr)
        return (priority.get(key, default), key)
    return key_func
```

### Example

```
class SimpleObject:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

lst = [SimpleObject('apple'), SimpleObject('banana'), SimpleObject('foo')]

priority = {
    'foo': 1,
}

print(sorted(lst, key=priority_sort_key('name', priority)))
```

### Output

```
[foo, apple, banana]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - thank you!